# Assembly Line Scheduling recursion solution error

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

basically I'm solving the assembly line scheduling problem in a recursion way, based on the formula provided [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-34-assembly-line-scheduling/)

The following information can be extracted from the problem statement to make it simpler:

Two assembly lines, 1 and 2, each with stations from 1 to n.

A car chassis must pass through all stations from 1 to n in order(in any of the two assembly lines). i.e. it cannot jump from station i to station j if they are not at one move distance.

The car chassis can move one station forward in the same line, or one station diagonally in the other line. It incurs an extra cost ti, j to move to station j from line i. No cost is incurred for movement in same line.

The time taken in station j on line i is ai,j.

Si,j represents a station j on line i.

Breaking the problem into smaller sub-problems:
We can easily find the ith factorial if (i-1)th factorial is known. Can we apply the similar funda here?
If the minimum time taken by the chassis to leave station Si, j-1 is known, the minimum time taken to leave station Si, j can be calculated quickly by combining ai, j and ti, j.

T1(j) indicates the minimum time taken by the car chassis to leave station j on assembly line 1.

T2(j) indicates the minimum time taken by the car chassis to leave station j on assembly line 2.

Base cases: 
The entry time ei comes into picture only when the car chassis enters the car factory.

Time taken to leave first station in line 1 is given by:
T1(1) = Entry time in Line 1 + Time spent in station S1,1
T1(1) = e1 + a1,1
Similarly, time taken to leave first station in line 2 is given by:
T2(1) = e2 + a2,1

Recursive Relations:
If we look at the problem statement, it quickly boils down to the below observations:
The car chassis at station S1,j can come either from station S1, j-1 or station S2, j-1.

Case #1: Its previous station is S1, j-1
The minimum time to leave station S1,j is given by:
T1(j) = Minimum time taken to leave station S1, j-1 + Time spent in station S1, j
T1(j) = T1(j-1) + a1, j

Case #2: Its previous station is S2, j-1
The minimum time to leave station S1, j is given by:
T1(j) = Minimum time taken to leave station S2, j-1 + Extra cost incurred to change the assembly line + Time spent in station S1, j
T1(j) = T2(j-1) + t2, j + a1, j

The minimum time T1(j) is given by the minimum of the two obtained in cases #1 and #2.
T1(j) = min((T1(j-1) + a1, j), (T2(j-1) + t2, j + a1, j))
Similarly the minimum time to reach station S2, j is given by:
T2(j) = min((T2(j-1) + a2, j), (T1(j-1) + t1, j + a2, j))

The total minimum time taken by the car chassis to come out of the factory is given by:
Tmin = min(Time taken to leave station Si,n + Time taken to exit the car factory)
Tmin = min(T1(n) + x1, T2(n) + x2)

The dynamic programming version is good, however, there is some hidden bug in my recursive version, could someone help me figure out the bug?
Thanks.

```
package DP;

public class AssemblyLineScheduling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{4, 5, 3, 2},
                         {2, 10, 1, 4}};
        int[][] t = {{0, 7, 4, 5},
                         {0, 9, 2, 8}};
        int[] e = {10, 12};
        int[] x = {18, 7};
        System.out.println(carAssemblyDP(a, t, e, x));
        System.out.println(carAssembly(a, t, e, x));
    }

    public static int carAssembly(int[][] a, int[][] t, int[] e, int[] x){
        int n = a[0].length-1;
        return Math.min(carAssemblyRec(a,t, e, x, n, 0) + x[0], 
                                carAssemblyRec(a,t, e, x, n, 1) + x[1]);
    }

    public static int carAssemblyRec(int[][] a, int[][] t, int[] e, int[] x, int n, int line){
        if(n == 0){
            return e[line] + a[line][0];
        }

        int T0 = Math.min(carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 0) + a[0][n]
                                , carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 1) + t[1][n] + a[0][n]);
        int T1 = Math.min(carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 1) + a[1][n]
                                , carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 0) + t[0][n] + a[1][n]);

        return Math.min(T0, T1);
    }

    public static int carAssemblyDP(int[][] a, int[][] t, int[] e, int[] x){
        int n = a[0].length;
        int[] T1 = new int[n];
        int[] T2 = new int[n];

        T1[0] = e[0] + a[0][0];
        T2[0] = e[1] + a[1][0];

        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            T1[i] = Math.min(T1[i-1]+a[0][i], T2[i-1]+t[1][i]+a[0][i]);
            T2[i] = Math.min(T2[i-1]+a[1][i], T1[i-1]+t[0][i]+a[1][i]);
        }

        return Math.min(T1[n-1]+x[0], T2[n-1]+x[1]);
    }
}
```

The DP output is 35, which is correct, but recursive version output is 29, which obviously wrong.

Comment: Debug? Also, don't force us to click on your links - put whatever necessary to understanding the question in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question.

```
public static int carAssemblyRec(int[][] a, int[][] t, int[] e, int[] x, int n, int line){  
    if(n == 0){  
        return e[line] + a[line][0];  
    }  

    int T0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  
    int T1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  
    if(line == 0){      
        T0 = Math.min(carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 0) + a[0][n],             
                            carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 1) + t[1][n] + a[0][n]);    
    }else if(line == 1){       
        T1 = Math.min(carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 1) + a[1][n],             
                             carAssemblyRec(a, t, e, x, n-1, 0) + t[0][n] + a[1][n]);   
    }  

    return Math.min(T0, T1);  
}
```